# Missing template when uploading files with Paperclip (only when form is remote: true)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, forms, paperclip

I am working on a Rails app. I have a form where the user can submit some files. The form is doing an AJAX call (it has the remote: true attribute). Whenever I want to send a file using the "f.file_field :banner" helper, the server responds with

```
Missing template posts/update with {:locale=>[:fr], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :slim]}. Searched in: ...
```

I have tried to add a respond_to block into my controller but then the server throws an ActionController::UnknownFormat.

Why is it not rendering my JS template ONLY when I submit a file? The form works fine when I just submit text.

Thank you for you help!

EDIT:

My form:

```
= bootstrap_form_for @section, remote: true  do |f|
 = f.file_field :banner
 ...
```

My controller:

```
# PATCH/PUT /sections/1
def update
  @section.update(section_params)
  manage_photos
  render "posts/update"
end
```

Comment: File uploading via ajax requires a bit of extra work, you can't just add a `remote: true` and expect it to work.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking but I can't find anything regarding this online. Any idea?

Comment: Thanks, I found out. I'll accept the solution whenever I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:
Using the [remotipart gem](https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart) !

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is specifically the line in your controller:

```
render "posts/update"
```

in your views directory, do you have a file posts/update.html.erb or the like.  That is what it is trying to render.  It can't find the file.  What are you trying to do with that line?

UPDATE:

Try doing this:

```
render 'posts/update', formats: [:js]
```

Comment: Yes I have "posts/update.js.erb". I don't think that's the issue since it works when I don't submit files.  As sevenseacat said, "File uploading via ajax requires a bit of extra work". I need to find out how now!

Comment: It looks like it is looking for a posts/update.html.erb. the missing template thinks you're rending html format, not js.